# How to add a new line with print when another variable is in place (Python 3.x)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to learning Python 3.0 and I am trying to solve an issue I have with making a list and printing at the end of it a new line to separate printing between two strings.

I.E.

```
list_1 = ['Autumn', 'Mary', 'Ditto', 'Gamma']
print(list_1)
print(list_1[2])

Output:
['Autumn', 'Mary', 'Ditto', 'Gamma']
Ditto
```

I was wondering is it possible I can add a new line in the first print() statement?

So I could end up with:

```
['Autumn', 'Mary', 'Ditto', 'Gamma']

Ditto
```

Thank you for any help whatsoever on this question. I really appreciate it!

Comment: `print(list_1, "\n")` or `print(list_1, end="\n\n")` or `print(list_1, list_1[2], sep="\n\n")` or `print(list_1) ; print() ; print(list_1[2])`... take your pick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, set `end="\n\n"` to add an extra newline or as many as you want:

```
print(list_1, end="\n\n")
print(list_1[2])
```

Or a single print using *sep*:

```
print(list_1, list_1[2], sep="\n\n")
```